# Autocomplete is not working after Postback in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

In my mvc application i'm appending jquery autocomplete to the searchbox. my problem is at first time autocomplete is working fine. it shows the related items when ever we type in the searchbox. after selecting one of the item it will redirect to another page. where the searchbox autocomplete is not working.
Here is my code:

View:

```
<div id="targetDiv">
@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { id = "SearchBox", @class = "SearchBox" })
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(getItems);
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    //We have used keyup event to track the user enter value in the textbox.
    $("#SearchBox").keyup(function () {
        //Fetching the textbox value.
        var query = $(this).val();
        //Calling GetItems method.
        getItems(query);
    });

    function getItems(query) {
        //var path = '@Url.Action("Suggest", "Home")';
        //Here we are using ajax get method to fetch data from the list based on the user entered value in the textbox.
        //We are sending query i.e textbox as data.
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action( "RemoteData", "Home")',
            data: { "query": query },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Data != null) {
                    if ($("#targetUL") != undefined) {
                        //If the UL element is not null or undefined we are clearing it, so that the result is appended in new UL every next time.
                        $("#targetUL").remove();
                    }
                    //assigning json response data to local variable. It is basically list of values.
                    data = response.Data;
                    //appending an UL element to show the values.
                    $("#targetDiv").append($("<ul id='targetUL'></ul>"));
                    //Removing previously added li elements to the list.
                    $("#targetUL").find("li").remove();
                    //We are iterating over the list returned by the json and for each element we are creating a li element and appending the li element to ul element.
                    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                        //On click of li element we are calling a method.
                        $("#targetUL").append($("<li class='targetLI' onclick='javascript:appendTextToTextBox(this)'>" + value + "</li>"));

                    });
                }
                else {
                    //If data is null the we are removing the li and ul elements.
                    $("#targetUL").find("li").remove();
                    $("#targetUL").remove();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            }
        });
    }
});

//This method appends the text oc clicked li element to textbox.
function appendTextToTextBox(e) {
    //Getting the text of selected li element.
    var textToappend = e.innerText;
    //setting the value attribute of textbox with selected li element.
    $("#SearchBox").val(textToappend);
    //Removing the ul element once selected element is set to textbox.
    $("#targetUL").remove();
}
</script>
```

controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoteData(string query)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        SearchModel searchmodel = new SearchModel();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = searchmodel.FilteredSearchProductDisplay(query, 5, 0);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(dr["ProductName"]);
            }
        }

        return Json(new { Data = list });
    }
```

Redirected-Page:

```
if (@Model.dtProduct.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    <div style="width:100%; height:auto;">@Html.Raw(@Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ThumbnailFilename"])</div>
    <br />
        if (ViewBag.RedirectedFromPage == "Search" || ViewBag.RedirectedFromPage == "OfferProduct")
        {
            if (@Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["Stock"].ToString().Length > 0)
            {  
                <table id ="priceTable">
                <tr>
                @if(@offerPrice > 0)
                {
                    <td style="width:10%" class="divSizehPrice"><label>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])@APrice.ToString("0.00")</label></td>
                    <td style="width:90%" class="divSizehPrice"><label>RRP&nbsp;</label><p>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])@Price.ToString("0.00")</p></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td colspan=2 style="width:90%" class="divSizehPrice"><p>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])@APrice.ToString("0.00")</p></td>
                }                    
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="divPrice2"style="display:none">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])</td>
                    <td><div id="PriceDiv2"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </div>
                <br />
                <a href="@Url.Action("Currency", "Product", new { ProductId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductId"], ProductpriceId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPriceId"], page = @Model.Page, BrandId = @Model.BrandId, CategoryId = @Model.CategoryId })">Change currency</a>
                <br />
                <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { ProductId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductId"], ProductpriceId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPriceId"], ProductPrice = @APrice })" type="button">Add to Shopping Cart</a>
            }
            else
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("SelectedProductDisplay", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { ProductId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductId"], ProductpriceId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPriceId"] }))
                {
                <b>Out of stock</b>
                <br />
                @*<p>Please enter your email address below and we will contact you when it comes back in to stock.</p>
                <br />
                <label>Email:</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OutOfStockEmail, new { id = "emailid" })
                <br />
                <div id="erroremail" class="validationColor" style="width:100%; text-align:center"></div>
                <label>@Model.OutOfStockStatus</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Notify Me" onclick="return checkEmail()"/>*@
                }
                <a href="@Url.Action("ContinueShoping", "Product")" type="button" data-theme="f">Continue Shopping</a>
            }
            <br />

            <div class="divSearchHeader">
            <p>@Html.Raw(Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductName"])</p>
            <br />
            </div>
            <div class="divSearchContent">
            @Html.Raw(@Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductDescription"])
            </div>
            <div class="divSearchContent">
            @Html.Raw(@Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["Description"])
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
                <table style="width:100%" id="priceTable1">
                @if (offerPrice > 0)
                {
                    <tr>
                    <td style="width:25%"><div class="divSizehPrice">@APrice.ToString("0.00")</div></td>
                    <td style="width:75%"><div class="divSizehPrice"><p><label>RRP&nbsp;</label>@Price.ToString("0.00")</p></div></td>
                    </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>                        
                    <td colspan=2 class="divSizehPrice"><p>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])@APrice.ToString("0.00")</p></td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </table>
                <div id="divPrice1"style="display:none" class="divSizehPrice">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Raw(@Model.dtcurrentCurrency.Rows[0]["HTMLENTITY"])</td>
                    <td><div id="PriceDiv1"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </div>

                <br />
                <a href="@Url.Action("Currency", "Product")">Change currency</a>
                <br />
                <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { ProductId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductId"], ProductpriceId = @Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPriceId"], ProductPrice = @APrice })" type="button" data-theme="f">Add to Shopping Cart</a>
                <br />
                <div class="divSearchHeader">
                <p>@Html.Raw(Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["Name"])</p>
                <br />
                </div>
                <div class="divSearchContent">
                @Html.Raw(@Model.dtProduct.Rows[0]["Description"])
                </div>
        }
}
else
{
    <p>No records found.</p>
}
```

Comment: Does the $("#SearchBox").keyup function call when you redirect ?

Comment: @Rakhita yes, keyup function call working fine

Comment: in the DEveloper tools in the browser can you see the request going to RemoteData ??

Comment: @ScottSelby i tried all the options, No solution could be obtained

Comment: @Rakhita,@Scott Selby some times the keyup function also not working.

Comment: this fails in all the browsers or in particular ?

Comment: Are you really using this jquery autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default ? I feel like we're missing some code.

Comment: @Rakhita in all browser

Comment: @BartBurg that is also not working in mvc application, and that is only for some list, here i'm taking the list from database.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. You can replace the list when you get it from the database like so: .autocomplete({source: []});

Comment: @BartBurg at the first time it is working fine, after post it is not working. even keyup function also not working.

Comment: And if you do this first: .autocomplete("destroy"); ?

Comment: @BartBurg already tried that one also.

Comment: Is the code you gave us is of the second page? Or the first? Did you try debugging using chrome development tools or firebug? I'm geussing the problem is not related to the postback or the first page but only to the js in the second page..

Comment: @AdamTal i'm placing the entire code in _layout.cshtml page. this page is layout for the all the remaining pages.

Comment: And have you tried debugging the javascript?

Comment: @AdamTal at first request all are working fine. after postback the keyup function is not working properly. some times the function is working and some times it is not working.

Comment: i find that you are removing the list items from this id targetUL. what are you populating in it?

Comment: @Saurabh targetUl is appended through script. in that list i'm populating the list from database.

Comment: is the ajax being called at all? check out the network tabs in inspector

Comment: @LeeGary at the first time every thing working fine, like key press, ajax call,etc..., after selecting one item among the list it will redirect to another view. there even keypup function is not woring. when ever i refresh the page 2 to 3 times again the autocomplete works.otherwise autocomplete is not working.

Comment: awaiting answers-> to all who commented on post. please help

Answer (score 0):

Please use live instead simple keyup:

```
$('selector').live('keyup',function(){

//your code

});
```

Comment: i tried this one also. but it is not working after post back in my mvc application.

Comment: after post back the script function is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used Jquery AutoComplete Search Box it is working fine the only difference is in Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    // Return the Result list store in searchResultList
    return Json(searchResultList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

- Removed Httpost Attribute
- While Returning Json, use the 2nd Overload Method JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Hope it helps you, Please note I am using MVC4 VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`$('sel').on('keyup',function(){`

//your code

});

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$("body").delegate("selector","keyup",function(e){//your code.})
```

Comment: The user is deleted or disassociated from the account. So there is no one who can *try* this to verify. You should add an explanation **why** this answers the question, so this has some value for future readers. You can edit your answer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('selector').on('input', function(){
// Do your stuff here
});
```

Check the 'input' event,